# "Exception: @error: Solution not Found" on and off while solving the same problem

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I am solving multiple optimization problems with the Gekko optimization suite. I generate random numbers for three variables (book3.csv) and import them to python as initial values and parameters. I run optimization solver and collect the results. It works well. However, when I tried this about 20 times to check, I received an error message of *Exception: @error: Solution not Found* several times. It stops at the same location: *...gekko.py line 2174, in solve raise Exception(response)*

I collected the value of control variables, `u`, at each round of optimization, `i`, at each time points, `j`, and saved it at a dataframe, utot, in order to track all the decisions made at each time for each round. I noticed that the last column (at the last time points) of `utot` has some positive values, which I think shouldn't be. I intentionally put `Pe0=0`, so that `u=0` is optimum at all time points, but still the last column of `utot` has some positive value. I am not sure what am I missing here.

[image]

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import random


file_path='./Book3.csv'
d=pd.read_csv("Book3.csv")
dftemp = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
na=len(dftemp)


# time points
n=51 
year=50

# constants
Pa0 = 1 
Pe0 = 0
C = 10 
r = 0.05 
k=50
shift=100
ll=0.5*random.rand(n)

index = range(0, na)
columns = range(0, n)
columns1 = range(0, 1)

#Dataframe to collect results
Atot=pd.DataFrame(index=index,columns=columns)
Etot=pd.DataFrame(index=index,columns=columns)
utot=pd.DataFrame(index=index,columns=columns)
PVtot=pd.DataFrame(index=index,columns=columns1)
    
for i in range(0,na):
    # create GEKKO model
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)

    m.time = np.linspace(0,year,n)
    t=m.time

    
    A0=dftemp.loc[i][0]
    h=dftemp.loc[i][1]
    emax=dftemp.loc[i][2]    

    u = m.MV(value=0,lb=0, ub=emax) 
    u.STATUS = 1
    u.DCOST = 0
    
    A = m.SV(value=A0)
    E = m.SV(value=0)
    t = m.Param(value=m.time)
    Pe = m.Var(value=Pe0)
    d = m.Var(value=1)
    l = m.Param(value=ll)
    
    # Equation
    m.Equation(A.dt()==-u)
    m.Equation(E.dt()==u)
    m.Equation(Pe.dt()==-Pe/k)
    m.Equation(d==m.exp(-t*r))
    m.Equation(A>=0)
        
    # Objective (Utility)
    J = m.Var(value=0)
    
    # Final objective
    Jf = m.FV()
    Jf.STATUS = 1
    m.Connection(Jf,J,pos2='end')
    m.Equation(J.dt() == m.log(A+E*(1-l))*h*Pa0-r*C*u+E*Pe+shift)*d
    
  
    # maximize U
    m.Maximize(Jf)
    
    # options
    m.options.IMODE = 6  # optimal control
    m.options.NODES = 3  # collocation nodes
    m.options.SOLVER = 3 # solver (IPOPT)
    
    # solve optimization problem
    m.solve()
    
    # print profit
    print('Optimal Profit: ' + str(Jf.value[0]))
 

    for j in range(0,n):
        Atot.loc[i][j]=A.value[j]
        Etot.loc[i][j]=E.value[j]
        utot.loc[i][j]=u.value[j]
    PVtot.loc[i][0]=Jf.value[0]
    
print(PVtot.sum())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `m.options.TIME_SHIFT=0` to avoid advancing in time if the initial conditions should remain the same. The default is `m.options.TIME_SHIFT=1` where all of the prior values are shifted left and the second horizon point becomes the first time point. This is the default for applications that are running in real-time to a physical process. Each cycle, the simulation or optimal control problem advances one time step ahead.

The last point in the horizon sometimes has no effect on the objective function so the solver isn't forced to move it to a particular value. This can be checked by fixing the last value with `m.fix_final(utot,100)` and see if this changes the objective function value. If the objective function value doesn't change then the solver will not find a unique solution for this value. If you'd like to make it unique then include an additional objective such as `m.Minimize(1e-5 * utot**2)`.

When submitting questions, please include all of the files needed to reproduce the behavior. Here are some tips on creating a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).